# Compile erros installing Kinetic on Pi 2 Jessie

Tags: ros, compile, ros-kinetic, raspberrypi, jessie

[image: Rosanswers logo]

20160102  I am installing Kinetic on a raspberry pi 2 Jessie

I think I'm getting errors on connection.cpp and subscriber.cpp?

My directory structure is this:
/home/dwulkan/robot/ros/catkin_ws

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
This is where I was in the installation when the error occurred
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
3.3  Building the catkin Workspace
Once you have completed downloading the packages and have resolved the dependencies, you are ready to build the catkin packages.

Invoke catkin_make_isolated:

$ sudo ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release --install-space /opt/ros/kinetic

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
The error message(s)
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/roscpp.dir/src/libros/network.cpp.o
[ 36%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/roscpp.dir/src/libros/master.cpp.o
[ 36%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/roscpp.dir/src/libros/subscriber.cpp.o
[ 38%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/roscpp.dir/src/libros/common.cpp.o
[ 39%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/roscpp.dir/src/libros/publisher_link.cpp.o
[ 40%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/roscpp.dir/src/libros/service_publication.cpp.o
[ 42%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/roscpp.dir/src/libros/connection.cpp.o
c++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.9/README.Bugs for instructions.
CMakeFiles/roscpp.dir/build.make:110: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/roscpp.dir/src/libros/subscriber.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/roscpp.dir/src/libros/subscriber.cpp.o] Error 4
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
c++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.9/README.Bugs for instructions.
CMakeFiles/roscpp.dir/build.make:158: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/roscpp.dir/src/libros/publisher_link.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/roscpp.dir/src/libros/publisher_link.cpp.o] Error 4

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
connection.cpp

/*

- Software License Agreement (BSD License)
- 
- Copyright (c) 2008, Willow Garage, Inc.
- All rights reserved.
- 
- Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
- modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
- are met:
- 
- - Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
- ```
  notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
  ```
- - Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above
- ```
  copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following
  ```
- ```
  disclaimer in the documentation and/or other materials provided
  ```
- ```
  with the distribution.
  ```
- - Neither the name of Willow Garage, Inc. nor the names of its
- ```
  contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
  ```
- ```
  from this software without specific prior written permission.
  ```
- 
- THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
- "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
- LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS
- FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
- COPYRIGHT OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT,
- INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING,
- BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES;
- LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER
- CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT
- LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN
- ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE
- POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
  */

#include "ros/connection.h"
#include "ros/transport/transport.h"
#include "ros/file_log.h"

#include <ros/assert.h>

#include <boost/shared_array.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

namespace ros
{

Connection::Connection()
: is_server_(false)
, dropped_(false)
, read_filled_(0)
, read_size_(0)
, reading_(false)
, has_read_callback_(0)
, write_sent_(0)
, write_size_(0)
, writing_(false)
, has_write_callback_(0)
, sending_header_error_(false)
{
}

Connection::~Connection()
{
ROS_DEBUG_NAMED("superdebug", "Connection destructing, dropped=%s", dropped_ ? "true" : "false");

drop(Destructing);
}

void Connection::initialize(const TransportPtr& transport, bool is_server, const HeaderReceivedFunc& header_func)
{
ROS_ASSERT(transport);

transport_ = transport;
header_func_ = header_func;
is_server_ = is_server;

transport_->setReadCallback(boost::bind(&Connection::onReadable, this, *1));
transport*->setWriteCallback(boost::bind(&Connection::onWriteable, this, *1));
transport*->setDisconnectCallback(boost::bind(&Connection::onDisconnect, this, _1));

if (header_func)
{
read(4, boost::bind(&Connection::onHeaderLengthRead, this, _1, _2, _3, _4));
}
}

boost::signals2::connection Connection::addDropListener(const DropFunc& slot)
{
boost::recursive_mutex::scoped_lock lock(drop_mutex_);
return drop_signal_.connect(slot);
}

void Connection::removeDropListener(const boost::signals2::connection& c)
{
boost::recursive_mutex::scoped_lock lock(drop_mutex_);
c.disconnect();
}

void Connection::onReadable(const TransportPtr& transport)
{
(void)transport;
ROS_ASSERT(transport == transport_);

readTransport();
}

void Connection::readTransport()
{
boost::recursive_mutex::scoped_try_lock lock(read_mutex_);

if (!lock.owns_lock() || dropped_ || reading_)
{
return;
}

reading_ = true;

while (!dropped_ && has_read_callback_)
{
ROS_ASSERT(read_buffer_);
uint32_t to_read = read_size_ - read_filled_;
if (to_read > 0)
{
int32_t bytes_read = transport_->read(read_buffer_.get() + read_filled_, to_read);
ROS_DEBUG_NAMED("superdebug", "Connection read %d bytes", bytes_read);
if (dropped_)
{
return;
}
else if (bytes_read < 0)
{
// Bad read, throw away results and report error
ReadFinishedFunc callback;
callback = read_callback_;
read_callback_.clear();
read_buffer_.reset();
uint32_t size = read_size_;
read_size_ = 0;
read_filled_ = 0;
has_read_callback_ = 0;

```
    if (callback)
    {
      callback(shared_from_this(), read_buffer_, size, false);
    }

    break;
  }

  read_filled_ += bytes_read;
}

ROS_ASSERT((int32_t)read_size_ >= 0);
ROS_ASSERT((int32_t)read_filled_ >= 0);
ROS_ASSERT_MSG(read_filled_ <= read_size_, "read_filled_ = %d, read_size_ = %d", read_filled_, read_size_);

if (read_filled_ == read_size_ && !dropped_)
{
  ReadFinishedFunc callback;
  uint32_t size;
  boost::shared_array<uint8_t> buffer;

  ROS_ASSERT(has_read_callback_);

  // store off the read info in case another read() call is made from within the callback
  callback = read_callback_;
  size = read_size_;
  buffer = read_buffer_;
  read_callback_.clear();
  read_buffer_.reset();
  read_size_ = 0;
  read_filled_ = 0;
  has_read_callback_ = 0;

  ROS_DEBUG_NAMED("superdebug", "Calling read callback");
  callback(shared_from_this(), buffer, size, true);
}
else
{
  break;
}
```

}

if (!has_read_callback_)
{
transport_->disableRead();
}

reading_ = false;
}

void Connection::writeTransport()
{
boost::recursive_mutex::scoped_try_lock lock(write_mutex_);

if (!lock.owns_lock() || dropped_ || writing_)
{
return;
}

writing_ = true;
bool can_write_more = true;

while (has_write_callback_ && can_write_more && !dropped_)
{
uint32_t to_write = write_size_ - write_sent_;
ROS_DEBUG_NAMED("superdebug", "Connection writing %d bytes", to_write);
int32_t bytes_sent = transport_->write(write_buffer_.get() + write_sent_, to_write);
ROS_DEBUG_NAMED("superdebug", "Connection wrote %d bytes", bytes_sent);

```
if (bytes_sent < 0)
{
  writing_ = false;
  return;
}

write_sent_ += bytes_sent;

if (bytes_sent < (int)write_size_ - (int)write_sent_)
{
  can_write_more = false;
}

if (write_sent_ == write_size_ && !dropped_)
{
  WriteFinishedFunc callback;

  {
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(write_callback_mutex_);
    ROS_ASSERT(has_write_callback_);
    // Store off a copy of the callback in case another write() call happens in it
    callback = write_callback_;
    write_callback_ = WriteFinishedFunc();
    write_buffer_ = boost::shared_array<uint8_t>();
    write_sent_ = 0;
    write_size_ = 0;
    has_write_callback_ = 0;
  }

  ROS_DEBUG_NAMED("superdebug", "Calling write callback");
  callback(shared_from_this());
}
```

}

{
boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(write_callback_mutex_);
if (!has_write_callback_)
{
transport_->disableWrite();
}
}

writing_ = false;
}

void Connection::onWriteable(const TransportPtr& transport)
{
(void)transport;
ROS_ASSERT(transport == transport_);

writeTransport();
}

void Connection::read(uint32_t size, const ReadFinishedFunc& callback)
{
if (dropped_ || sending_header_error_)
{
return;
}

{
boost::recursive_mutex::scoped_lock lock(read_mutex_);

```
ROS_ASSERT(!read_callback_);

read_callback_ = callback;
read_buffer_ = boost::shared_array<uint8_t>(new uint8_t[size]);
read_size_ = size;
read_filled_ = 0;
has_read_callback_ = 1;
```

}

transport_->enableRead();

// read immediately if possible
readTransport();
}

void Connection::write(const boost::shared_array<uint8_t>& buffer, uint32_t size, const WriteFinishedFunc& callback, bool immediate)
{
if (dropped_ || sending_header_error_)
{
return;
}

{
boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(write_callback_mutex_);

```
ROS_ASSERT(!write_callback_);

write_callback_ = callback;
write_buffer_ = buffer;
write_size_ = size;
write_sent_ = 0;
has_write_callback_ = 1;
```

}

transport_->enableWrite();

if (immediate)
{
// write immediately if possible
writeTransport();
}
}

void Connection::onDisconnect(const TransportPtr& transport)
{
(void)transport;
ROS_ASSERT(transport == transport_);

drop(TransportDisconnect);
}

void Connection::drop(DropReason reason)
{
ROSCPP_LOG_DEBUG("Connection::drop(%u)", reason);
bool did_drop = false;
{
boost::recursive_mutex::scoped_lock lock(drop_mutex_);
if (!dropped_)
{
dropped_ = true;
did_drop = true;
}
}

if (did_drop)
{
drop_signal_(shared_from_this(), reason);
transport_->close();
}
}

bool Connection::isDropped()
{
boost::recursive_mutex::scoped_lock lock(drop_mutex_);
return dropped_;
}

void Connection::writeHeader(const M_string& key_vals, const WriteFinishedFunc& finished_callback)
{
ROS_ASSERT(!header_written_callback_);
header_written_callback_ = finished_callback;

if (!transport_->requiresHeader())
{
onHeaderWritten(shared_from_this());
return;
}

boost::shared_array<uint8_t> buffer;
uint32_t len;
Header::write(key_vals, buffer, len);

uint32_t msg_len = len + 4;
boost::shared_array<uint8_t> full_msg(new uint8_t[msg_len]);
memcpy(full_msg.get() + 4, buffer.get(), len);
*((uint32_t*)full_msg.get()) = len;

write(full_msg, msg_len, boost::bind(&Connection::onHeaderWritten, this, _1), false);
}

void Connection::sendHeaderError(const std::string& error_msg)
{
M_string m;
m["error"] = error_msg;

writeHeader(m, boost::bind(&Connection::onErrorHeaderWritten, this, *1));
sending_header_error* = true;
}

void Connection::onHeaderLengthRead(const ConnectionPtr& conn, const boost::shared_array<uint8_t>& buffer, uint32_t size, bool success)
{
(void)size;
ROS_ASSERT(conn.get() == this);
ROS_ASSERT(size == 4);

if (!success)
return;

uint32_t len = *((uint32_t*)buffer.get());

if (len > 1000000000)
{
ROS_ERROR("a header of over a gigabyte was " 
"predicted in tcpros. that seems highly " 
"unlikely, so I'll assume protocol " 
"synchronization is lost.");
conn->drop(HeaderError);
}

read(len, boost::bind(&Connection::onHeaderRead, this, _1, _2, _3, _4));
}

void Connection::onHeaderRead(const ConnectionPtr& conn, const boost::shared_array<uint8_t>& buffer, uint32_t size, bool success)
{
ROS_ASSERT(conn.get() == this);

if (!success)
return;

std::string error_msg;
if (!header_.parse(buffer, size, error_msg))
{
drop(HeaderError);
}
else
{
std::string error_val;
if (header_.getValue("error", error_val))
{
ROSCPP_LOG_DEBUG("Received error message in header for connection to [%s]: [%s]", transport_->getTransportInfo().c_str(), error_val.c_str());
drop(HeaderError);
}
else
{
ROS_ASSERT(header_func_);

```
  transport_->parseHeader(header_);

  header_func_(conn, header_);
}
```

}

}

void Connection::onHeaderWritten(const ConnectionPtr& conn)
{
ROS_ASSERT(conn.get() == this);
ROS_ASSERT(header_written_callback_);

header_written_callback_(conn);
header_written_callback_ = WriteFinishedFunc();
}

void Connection::onErrorHeaderWritten(const ConnectionPtr& conn)
{
(void)conn;
drop(HeaderError);
}

void Connection::setHeaderReceivedCallback(const HeaderReceivedFunc& func)
{
header_func_ = func;

if (transport_->requiresHeader())
read(4, boost::bind(&Connection::onHeaderLengthRead, this, _1, _2, _3, _4));
}

std::string Connection::getCallerId()
{
std::string callerid;
if (header_.getValue("callerid", callerid))
{
return callerid;
}

return std::string("unknown");
}

std::string Connection::getRemoteString()
{
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "callerid=[" << getCallerId() << "] address=[" << transport_->getTransportInfo() << "]";
return ss.str();
}

}

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
subscriber.cpp

/*

- Copyright (C) 2009, Willow Garage, Inc.
- 
- Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
- modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
- - Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice,
- ```
  this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
  ```
- - Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
- ```
  notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
  ```
- ```
  documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
  ```
- - Neither the names of Stanford University or Willow Garage, Inc. nor the names of its
- ```
  contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived from
  ```
- ```
  this software without specific prior written permission.
  ```
- 
- THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS"
- AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE
- IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE
- ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE
- LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR
- CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF
- SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS
- INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN
- CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE)
- ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE
- POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
  */

#include "ros/subscriber.h"
#include "ros/node_handle.h"
#include "ros/topic_manager.h"

namespace ros
{

Subscriber::Impl::Impl()
: unsubscribed_(false)
{ }

Subscriber::Impl::~Impl()
{
ROS_DEBUG("Subscriber on '%s' deregistering callbacks.", topic_.c_str());
unsubscribe();
}

bool Subscriber::Impl::isValid() const
{
return !unsubscribed_;
}

void Subscriber::Impl::unsubscribe()
{
if (!unsubscribed_)
{
unsubscribed_ = true;
TopicManager::instance()->unsubscribe(topic_, helper_);
node_handle_.reset();
helper_.reset();
}
}

Subscriber::Subscriber(const std::string& topic, const NodeHandle& node_handle,
const SubscriptionCallbackHelperPtr& helper)
: impl_(boost::make_shared())
{
impl_->topic_ = topic;
impl_->node_handle_ = boost::make_shared(node_handle);
impl_->helper_ = helper;
}

Subscriber::Subscriber(const Subscriber& rhs)
{
impl_ = rhs.impl_;
}

Subscriber::~Subscriber()
{
}

void Subscriber::shutdown()
{
if (impl_)
{
impl_->unsubscribe();
}
}

std::string Subscriber::getTopic() const
{
if (impl_)
{
return impl_->topic_;
}

```
return std::string();
```

}

uint32_t Subscriber::getNumPublishers() const
{
if (impl_ && impl_->isValid())
{
return TopicManager::instance()->getNumPublishers(impl_->topic_);
}

```
return 0;
```

}

} // namespace ros

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251140/compile-erros-installing-kinetic-on-pi-2-jessie/) by [DaveWulkan](https://answers.ros.org/users/28934/davewulkan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-01-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [suforeman](https://answers.ros.org/users/28415/suforeman/) on 2017-01-02**:
(converted to an answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

May I suggest an alternate solution.

You can download and install an image of Ubuntu 16.04 for the RPi 2 & 3.I'd recommend the server version with no GUI).

Then you can use apt-get to install ROS and packages.

https://ubuntu-mate.org/blog/ubuntu-mate-xenial-raspberry-pi/

---

Originally posted by [suforeman](https://answers.ros.org/users/28415/suforeman/) with karma: 300 on 2017-01-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-01-03**:
Seconded; if you're willing to install Ubuntu, the installation through apt-get is much faster and more reliable.